# Call filter only if textbox has value

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code that filters a excel sheet

```
With Sheets("Inventory on Hand").Range("A1:F1")
    .AutoFilter
    Call .AutoFilter(1, UserForm1.TextBox13.Text)
    Call .AutoFilter(3, UserForm1.TextBox15.Text)
    Call .AutoFilter(4, UserForm1.TextBox14.Text)
    Call .AutoFilter(5, UserForm1.TextBox16.Text)
End With
```

However, the problem with this is, if I were to leave `TextBox13` blank, column 1 will be filtered to rows that are blank, which is not what I want.

How do I apply the filter to that column if and only if the corresponding textbox has a value?

If `TextBox13` is blank, column1 should not be filtered at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
If Len(UserForm1.TextBox13.Text) <> 0 Then Call .AutoFilter(1, UserForm1.TextBox13.Text)
```

Or

```
If Not IsEmpty(UserForm1.TextBox13) Then Call .AutoFilter(1, UserForm1.Textbox13.Text)
```

Or maybe

```
If UserForm1.TextBox13.Value <> "" Then Call .AutoFilter(1, UserForm1.TextBox13.Text)
```

No way to test it atm so i leave it to you.

Answer (score 1):

You might make sure that if nothing is selected the filter from column one is removed, if it was filtered before. This would look something like:

```
If If UserForm1.TextBox13.Value <> "" Then
    Call .AutoFilter(1, UserForm1.TextBox13.Text)
Else
    .AutoFilter Field:=1
End If
```